# title: how can I find the correspondence between org.eclipse.jdt.core and eclipse releases?

Tags: eclipse

I am new to eclipse. Where can I find the org.eclipse.jdt.core version (e.g., [3.10.0,4.0.0) bundled with each official eclipse release. it would be tedious to find out by installing each eclipse version

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a versions list. You can download just the 'JDT Runtime Binary' for the various releases from the [Eclipse Projects Archives](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/). This is about 27Mb per release. This is just a zip file, you don't need to install it, just examine the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a tool like [p2-browser](https://github.com/ifedorenko/p2-browser). It will allow you to examine the contents of Eclipse P2 Update sites by just downloading the meta data.

### Using p2browser

Once you have started p2browser (see below), you should have a screen like this:

[image: initial screen]

Add 1 or more p2 sites to consider and allow the tool to download the metadata.

1. Press Add
2. Put the p2 site (e.g. for Mars: `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars`)
3. Press OK and wait for download
4. Repeat until you have all the versions you are interested in.

You should now have your added p2 sites listed in the tree viewer:

[image: sites listed]

Now you can add your plug-in or feature you are interested in, e.g. in your case `org.eclipse.jdt.core` in the filter box:

[image: filtered on jdt core]

Another example of what you can filter on, e.g. `org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group` for the JDT Feature

[image: JDT feature]

### Download/Install/Build

### Java Web Start

To use the p2 browser you may like to simply use Java Web Start, Run:

```
javaws  http://ifedorenko.github.com/p2-browser/javaws/com.ifedorenko.p2browser.jnlp
```

Or click [this link](http://ifedorenko.github.com/p2-browser/javaws/com.ifedorenko.p2browser.jnlp), as [docs](https://github.com/ifedorenko/p2-browser#java-webstart-launcher) show, results for using java web start may vary because of tightening security considerations of running arbitrary java downloaded from the web.

### Build and Run with Maven

You can build it with maven, as per the [docs](https://github.com/ifedorenko/p2-browser#building-and-running-p2-browser-locally). These are simplified instructions:

1. `git clone git@github.com:ifedorenko/p2-browser.git`
2. `cd p2-browser/`
3. `mvn clean package`
4. `cd com.ifedorenko.p2browser.rcp/target/products/com.ifedorenko.p2browser.rcp`
5. Linux x64: `linux/gtk/x86_64`, other platforms, choose the correct directory.
6. `./p2browser`